# INDY 10.1.5 - Which SSL dlls work with Delphi 2006?

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy, delphi-2006

I'm trying to connect to google documents (following Marco Cantu's excellent REST example) but I am getting the following SSL errors:

1) If I use the SSL dlls from openssl-0.9.8i-i386-win32.zip I get the error:

"Could not load SSL library"

2) If I use the SSL dlls from indy_OpenSSL096m.zip I get the error:

"Error connecting with SSL"

3) If I use the SSL dlls from openssl-0.9.8h-i386-win32-Indy-IntraWebEdition.zip I get the error:

"Could not load SSl Library"

Now I've researched this and there are a lot of recommendations with dead links to dlls about, including links on stack overflow. I suspect I need to find the SSL dlls that are compatible with the version of INDY I am using.

My question is, does anyone know exactly which SSL dlls are compatible with Delphi 2006 & INDY 10.1.5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem even after I upgrading to INDY 10.2.3 and I tryed every different version of the “libeay32.dll” and “ssleay32.dll” files I could find ... Like Matt I always got one of the two errors: "Could not load SSL library" or the "Error connecting with SSL" with something like "error:00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib" ...

I was very happy when I change the TidSSLioHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method to sslvSSLv23 and everything started working.

A bit more research and I quickly understood anytime I got the error "Could not load SSL library" I was using the wrong version of the DLL files and anytime I got the "Error connecting with SSL" with something like "error:00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib" I was using the wrong SSLOptions.Method value.

Other Info: I'm using Delphi 2006, INDY 10.2.3 and I'm runnin on WinXP Pro

This caused me so much pain, I hope this post will save someone some time.

Comment: Very useful comments, I'm sure these will help others in the same situation. Thanks.

Comment: +1 this fix did the trick although I had no idea what sslvSSLv23 meant before I read http://www.ehow.com/how_5953595_determine-ssl-protocol-version.html I am using the latest Indy9 on D5 Windows2000

Answer (score 3):

You could resort to some trial and error using downloads from the [Fulgan site](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

You might want to think about updating your copy of Indy and using the most recent OpenSSL DLLs.

Comment: I think you're right, I need to update INDY and use the most recent OpenSSL dlls.

Comment: I think it will make things simpler.

Comment: You know what drives me crazy on the Fulgain installers?  Some of the installers install directly into the windows installation folder (0.9.8h for instance) -- later installer versions give you a choice.  It seems like black magic finding working SSL dlls.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, since I have spent a lot of time getting this https thing to work, here are the results of my successful efforts.

1- Delphi 7

2- indy9.0.19_d7.exe

3- IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1; or,

IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv23; or,

IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv3;

I tried indy10.0.76_d7.exe and indy10.1.5_d7.exe under Delphi 7 and I cannot get them to install properly, let alone get HTTPS to work. I get the infamous message "Unit IdSysWin32 was compiled with a different version of IdException.EIdException." I searched for a solution to that problem on the web and couldn't find one - loads of others had the same message.

A useful site for testing https is https://msp.f-secure.com/web-test/common/test.html

Here is my source:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonHTTPSClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  ParamStringList: TStringList;
  s1: String;
  MemoryStream1: TMemoryStream;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1:  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin //  ssl works fine must have Indy version indy9.0.19_d7.exe and must use option  sslvSSLv23

  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil); 
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;

//  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1; // sslvSSLv1 works fine
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3; // sslvSSLv3 works fine
//  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; // sslvSSLv23 works fine
//  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv2;   sslvSSLv2 does not work
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

  ParamStringList := TStringList.Create;
  MemoryStream1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  s1 := IdHTTP1.Post('https://msp.f-secure.com/web-test/common/test.html', ParamStringList);
  MemoryStream1.Write(s1[1], Length(s1));
  MemoryStream1.Position := 0;
  MemoryStream1.SaveToFile('c:\temp\MemoryStream1.txt');
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('c:\temp\MemoryStream1.txt');
  MemoryStream1.Free;
  ParamStringList.Free;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.Free;
  IdHTTP1.Free;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine for me. I have Indy-10.1.5 and Delphi-7, Win-7x64 and SSL dlls from indy_OpenSSL096m.zip with your link https://msp.f-secure.com/web-test/common/test.html.
BUT only if SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23 or sslvTLSv1. I don't have "sslvTLSv23" or "sslvTLSv3" in drop-down list, I have "sslvSSLv2" and "sslvSSLv3" instead. And I'm using "IdHTTP1.get" as simplified version or request with no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware the more recent versions of Indy work with standard OpenSSL binaries.
[Download from here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). We produced a Delphi FTP client app a while ago using Indy with SSL connections and I'm sure we just shipped the current OpenSSL dlls.

Edit: Just checked the app directory and the DLLs we used are OpenSSL 0.9.8.2 (3-Aug-06). (It's an old app)

Edit 2: And I've just copied the more recent 0.9.8k dlls over and they work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Find the Indy version you are using.Copy the Indy dlls i.e libeay32.dll,libssl32.dll and
ssleay32.dll into the Windows/System 32 Folder.It will resolve the error "Could not Load SSL Library"