# STARTTLS error while sending email using Indy in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy10

I'm trying to send email from my application using the following code:

```
  Var
  MailMessage : TIdMessage;
  SMTP        : TIdSMTP
   .
   .
   .
 //setup SMTP
 SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
 SMTP.Port := 25;
 //setup mail message
 MailMessage.From.Address := 'fromMe@gmail.com';
 MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'ToSomeOne@hotmail.com';
 MailMessage.Subject := 'Test';
 MailMessage.Body.Text := 'Hello, It is Just for test';

 SMTP.Connect;
 SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
```

When i run it, it generates the following error

```
**ERROR: Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i29sm34080394wbp.22**
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with STARTTLS:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS and https://www.fastmail.fm/help/technology_ssl_vs_tls_starttls.html are both helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By putting the answers together you can get the following code. Don't forget as [`Nathanial Woolls`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33112/nathanial-woolls) mentioned [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717495/what-is-wrong-within-this-code-sending-email-using-indy-in-delphi-xe/7717903#7717903) to put the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` libraries for instance from [`here`](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) to your project folder or to a path from the [`following places`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications).

```
uses
  IdMessage, IdSMTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdGlobal, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase;

procedure SendEmail(const Recipients: string; const Subject: string; const Body: string);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Email: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  try
    SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    SMTP.Port := 587;
    SMTP.Username := 'yourusername@gmail.com';
    SMTP.Password := 'yourpassword';
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    Email.From.Address := 'yourusername@gmail.com';
    Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := Recipients;
    Email.Subject := Subject;
    Email.Body.Text := Body;

    SMTP.Connect;
    SMTP.Send(Email);
    SMTP.Disconnect;

  finally
    SMTP.Free;
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendEmail('recipient@whatever.com', 'Subject', 'Body');
end;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Get rid of the assignments to the `SSLHandler.Destination`, `SSLHandler.Host`, and `SSLHandler.Port` properties.  Those properties are filled in automatically by `Connect()`.

Answer (score 6):

`smtp.gmail.com` forces you to use an encrypted connection using STARTTLS.

Indy 9 does not support STARTTLS directly, but indy 10 does.

In Indy 10, before connecting to the server, you have to assign an
SSL-enabled IOHandler, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`,

See: http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.html

Add the following code:

```
var
...
SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

SSLHandler:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Form1);
SMTP.IOHandler:= SSLHandler;
SMTP.UseTLS:= utUseExplicitTLS;
SMTP.Username:= 'username';
SMTP.Password:= 'password';
SMTP.Port:= 587;
```

If you just SMTP to a non-encrypted SMTP-handler (your ISP's SMTP) you will not suffer this problem.

Comment: @Johna: saying _Indy 9 does not support this_ is wrong. Indy 9 does support SSL encryption, it just does not support the STARTTLS command that GMail's SMTP server requires. You can send the STARTTLS command manually with a few extra lines of code, though.  As for the `OnGetPassword` event, that only applies if a password-protected SSL certificate is being used (which is not the case with GMail).

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB, thanks for pointing that out, it's been a while since I used Indy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is it possible to send STARTTLS manually with Indy 8? I have an app which uses Indy 8. I can send emails using SSL connection but only if the server is using implicit TLS. I would like to add the support of STARTTLS. If it's possible, please tell me how

Answer (score 3):

The error is because Gmail uses SSL and TLS. You're going to need to use Indy's SSL IO handler as well as the proper [OpenSSL DLL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874677/indy-10-1-5-which-ssl-dlls-work) for your Indy version.

There a tutorial on getting this working [here](http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html).