# Problem sending an email via GMail with Indy SMTP client

Tags: delphi, smtp, gmail

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong (or not doing)?

Here is my procedure code:

```pascal
procedure TForm20.SendImage(const Comment, AImage: String);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
begin
  Msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  try
    Msg.From.Address := 'frostydennis7@gmail.com';
    Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'trevosedennis@gmail.com';
    Msg.Body.Text := 'hello dennis';
    Msg.Subject := 'free space';

    SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    try
      SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      SMTP.Port := 587;  
      //SMTP.Port := 465; //gives different error-connection closed gracefully but
      //no email is sent or received
         
      SMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
      SMTP.Username := 'frostydennis7@gmail.com';
      SMTP.Password := '$$$$$$$';

      SMTP.Connect;
      //fails with port 25- connection time out socket error
      //with port 465 it never gets past smtp connect.  shows 'closed graceflly'
      //with port 587 it gets past connect but then says
      //'must issue a STARTTLS command first' before smtp.send(msg)

      SMTP.Send(Msg);
    finally
      SMTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Msg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: 1) See if any of the responses in this thread help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717862/421195  2) Check your Delphi code against the Java/Python examples here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property.

On port 25 and 587, you must set `UseTLS` to `utUseExplicitTLS`, then `TIdSMTP` will issue a `STARTTLS` command to initiate an SSL/TLS handshake before sending emails.

On port 465, you must set `UseTLS` to `utUseImplicitTLS`, then `TIdSMTP` will initiate an SSL/TLS handshake immediately upon connecting, before reading the server's greeting.

Either way, using SSL/TLS requires assigning a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, to the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` property before connecting to the server, eg:

```pascal
var
  IO: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
...
IO := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(SMTP);
IO.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
// configure other IO properties as needed...

SMTP.IOHandler := IO;
```

Note that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` does not support TLS 1.3+. At this time, if you need to use TLS 1.3+ then try [this work-in-progress SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) for that purpose.