# Delphi,oAuth and Linked API, Access token giving Unauthorized

Tags: delphi, oauth, linkedin-api

I am working on a program which posts updates to LinkedIn.

I am using Delphi XE2,oAuth and LinkedIn API for the same. I am able to request token and authorize application. But I am getting error on when trying to Access token.

I am using oAuth for Delphi from http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/. For SSL I am using, TIdSSLIOHandlerSOcketOpenSSL with method sslvSSLv3.
I am trying to post the following.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken?oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_nonce=A7CB896D776BA2FEC05E9FBB66AD06B2&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=K%2F7uzf%2FjEvQ3u12a0Olimf%2FZxG4%3D&oauth_timestamp=1338019026&oauth_token=xxxx&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_verifier=53326
```

The result I am getting from Indy Http is giving bellow.

```
Http/1.1 401 – Unauthorized
```

Can anyone help me for fixing this.

Comment: Take a look at this comments that mention the XE2 Indy build as being a problem with used with SSL.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10823262/1120271

Comment: Found Solution.     IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 do
    begin
      SSLOptions.Method       := sslvSSLv3;
      SSLOptions.SSLVersions  := [sslvSSLv3];
      SSLOptions.Mode         := sslmBoth;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode   := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth  := 0;
      host := '';
    end;