# share data to LinkedIn User’s Profile

Tags: delphi, linkedin-api

I am working on a program which share data to LinkedIn User’s Profile. I am using Delphi XE2, OAuth and LinkedIn API for the same. I am able to Access token. But I am getting error on when trying to.
I am using [OAuth](http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/) for Delphi. For SSL I am using, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSOcketOpenSSL` with method sslvSSLv3. I am trying to post the following:

I am posting `(https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares)`as Url and
`(<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>';<share> <comment> hiSir</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>)` as Xml.

And my Idhttp header*****    `'Authorization: OAuth realm =https://api.linkedin.com/’',  oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_nonce=A7CB896D776BA2FEC05E9FBB66AD06B2&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=K%2F7uzf%2FjEvQ3u12a0Olimf%2FZxG4%3D&oauth_timestamp=1338019026&oauth_token=xxxx&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_verifier=53326`

The result I am getting from Indy Http is this: `Http/1.1 401 – Unauthorized`
Can anyone help me for fixing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10828270/1120271

Comment: Its different answer.Its belong to getting the access tokin.

Comment: Please Anyone help me. Till Now I am not posting xml with header. All time facing 401 error. My response is <status>401</status> <timestamp>1340895781480</timestamp> <request-id>BYE79V9AXB</request-id> <error-code>0</error-code> <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:2j71bnoc4x5f|3b2f15bd-a2c8-474f-ae05-541dd9b76468|*01|*01:1340895531:PxhePw0‌​/XHdvPz9cP3k/Px5WXz8=</message> </error> Please help me ...........