# share data to LinkedIn User’s Profile for status update

Tags: delphi, linkedin-api

I am working on a program which share data to LinkedIn User’s Profile. I am using Delphi XE2, OAuth and LinkedIn API for the same. I am able to Access token. But I am getting error on when trying to.
I am using OAuth for Delphi. For SSL I am using, TIdSSLIOHandlerSOcketOpenSSL with method sslvSSLv3. I am trying to post the following:

I am posting (https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares)as Url and
(';  hiSir`anyone`) as Xml.

And my Idhttp  Custom header*** ('oauth_consumer_key='+xxxxxxxxxxx+
              ',oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"'+',oauth_timestamp='+QuotedStr(ARequest.GenerateTimeStamp)+
              ',oauth_nonce='+QuotedStr(ARequest.GenerateNonce)+',oauth_version="1.0"'+
              ',oauth_token='+xxxxxxxxxx+',oauth_signature='+QuotedStr(sign));

The result I am getting from Indy Http is this: Http/1.1 401 – Unauthorized Can anyone help me for fixing this? Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828270/delphi-oauth-and-linked-api-access-token-giving-unauthorized) and this [article](http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/)

```
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL do begin 
 SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
 SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv3]; 
 SSLOptions.Mode := sslmBoth; 
 SSLOptions.VerifyMode := []; 
 SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0; 
 host := ''; 
end;
```

Comment: @vikas [Debugging LinkedIN](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/debugging-api-calls) Please specify which headers you are sending.

Comment: Still facing same issue and my http.request.customheader is Add('Authorization: OAuth realm="https://api.linkedin.com/",oauth_consumer_key='+'"'+Consumer.Key+'"'+
              ',oauth_token='+'"'+Token.Key+'"'+',oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"'+',oauth_signature='+'"'+sign+'"'+
              ',oauth_timestamp='+'"'+ARequest.GenerateTimeStamp+'"'+',oauth_nonce='+'"'+ARequest.GenerateNonce+'"'+
              ',oauth_version="1.0"');  please help me A1rPun

Comment: @vikas `'OAuth '+ 
'oauth_nonce="'+@@@@@+'",'+ 
'oauth_signature_method="'+@@@@@+'",'+
'oauth_timestamp="'+@@@@@+'",'+
'oauth_consumer_key="'+@@@@@+'",'+
'oauth_token="'+@@@@@+'",'+
'oauth_signature="'+@@@@@+'",'+
'oauth_version="'+@@@@@+'",'` Make sure you replace `@@@@@` with your variables.

Comment: Still facing same issue @A1rPun Please help me. I am using ssl with these property  SSLOptions.Method      := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1];
      SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmBoth;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      host := 'https://api.linkedin.com'; And Xml Then Post  http.post(Url,slist,Response);  And My Header is     Request.ContentType := 'application/xml';

Comment: Ok, I cant figure out what you are doing wrong.. can you please update your question to make everything more readable? Please specify you version of indy components and please add more code, with partial code I/we cant do much for you.

Comment: hi @ A1rPun i have posted another ques with code . please check that and answer me.

Comment: @ A1rPun Please help me. Did you not got my updated question.And I am using Indy 10 with delphi Xe2

Comment: [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080570/share-data-to-linkedin-api-users-profile-for-status-update) please accept this one when its solved?

Comment: I have tried updated indy(10.5.8) from svn Revision(4771). Still facing same issue 401 Unauthorized. Please help me @A1rPun. I am trying alot of solutions.

Comment: Hi @A1rPun did you not get my Ques. Please tell me something.I am getting own status in XML but not doing post Please help me. If You have some time Then I want to chat with you.So Please contact me.....

Comment: Please Anyone help me. Till Now I am not posting xml with header. All time facing 401 error. My response is <status>401</status> <timestamp>1340895781480</timestamp> <request-id>BYE79V9AXB</request-id> <error-code>0</error-code> <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:2j71bnoc4x5f|3b2f15bd-a2c8-474f-ae05-541dd9b76468|*01|*01:1340895531:PxhePw0‌​/XHdvPz9cP3k/Px5WXz8=</message> </error> Please help me ...........