# share data to LinkedIn api User’s Profile for status update

Tags: delphi, linkedin-api

I am working on a program which share data to LinkedIn User’s Profile. I am using Delphi XE2, OAuth and LinkedIn API for the same. I am able to get Access token. Then I want to update status. So my code is

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL ;
Url,sign  : String;
Response     : TStringStream;
slist        : TStringList;
str          : WideString;
Arequest1    : TOAuthRequest;
AuthHeader   : WideString;
begin
   with http do
   Begin
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSOcketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    with idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do
    begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1];
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmBoth;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      host := '';
    end;
    IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    AllowCookies := True;
    Request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
    Request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
    Request.ContentType := 'application/xml';
    Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    Request.Connection   := 'Keep-Alive';
    request.host := 'api.linkedin.com';
    Request.Accept := 'text/xml, */*';
    Request.UserAgent  :=  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0' ;
    HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
   end;
     Url := 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares';
     Consumer    := nil;
     Consumer    := TOAuthConsumer.Create(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
     Arequest1   := TOAuthRequest.Create(Url);
     sign        := HMAC.build_signature(Arequest1,Consumer,Token);
     sign        := TOAuthUtil.urlEncodeRFC3986(sign);
     http.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
     AuthHeader     := 'OAuth '+ 'oauth_nonce="'+Arequest1.GenerateNonce+'",'+  'oauth_signature_method="'+HMAC.get_name+'",'+ 'oauth_timestamp="'+Timestamp+'",'+ 'oauth_consumer_key="'+Consumer.Key+'",'+ 'oauth_token="'+Token.Key+'",'+ 'oauth_signature="'+sign+'",'+ 'oauth_version="1.0"';
      http.Request.CustomHeaders.Add(AuthHeader);
      slist       := TStringList.Create;

      slist.Text  := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><share><comment>Posting from the API using XML</comment>'+
                     '<content><title>A title for your share</title><submitted-url>http://developer.linkedin.com</submitted-url>'+
                     '<submitted-image-url>http://lnkd.in/Vjc5ec</submitted-image-url></content><visibility>'+
                     '<code>anyone</code></visibility></share>';
    Response    := TStringStream.Create;
    http.Request.ContentLength  := length(slist.Text);
  try
     http.post(Url,slist,Response);
  Finally
    ShowMessage(Response.DataString);
    http.Free;
    ARequest.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am facing **401 unauthorized**. Please check my ques @A1rPun. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing a full code sample. I've seen you commented on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981160/share-data-to-linkedin-users-profile-for-status-update) that you use indy 10 in Delphi XE2.

The problem could be that there is something wrong with the SSL authentication within indy 10. [Full explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818806/how-can-i-get-delphi-xe2-to-talk-to-google-calendar-apis-over-ssl/10823262#10823262) What you can do is trying to get a stable version of the indy components.

The code seem to have no errors except for a couple of resources that could have been freed ;).

I really hope when updating your indy your problem will solve.

Comment: I have tried updated indy(10.5.8) from svn Revision(4771). Still facing same issue 401 Unauthorized. Please help me @A1rPun. I am trying alot of solutions.

Comment: Hi @A1rPun did you not get my Ques. Please tell me something.I am getting own status in XML but not doing post Please help me. If You have some time Then I want to chat with you.So Please contact me.....

Comment: Please Anyone help me. Till Now I am not posting xml with header. All time facing 401 error. My response is   <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1340895781480</timestamp>
  <request-id>BYE79V9AXB</request-id>  
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:2j71bnoc4x5f|3b2f15bd-a2c8-474f-ae05-541dd9b76468|*01|*01:1340895531:PxhePw0/XHdvPz9cP3k/Px5WXz8=</message>
</error>     Please help me ............